# How to sort references by year if they have the same author

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I want to chronologically sort the citations where the author is printed only once (same author, 2 or more papers from different years). I am trying with the option "citestyle=authoryear-comp." However, it only works for some cases. 
Here what I have in my .tex file :

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio1.bib}
\begin{document}
\parencite{klaauw.96,klaauw.12}
\parencite{stineb.96,stineb.12}
\end{document}
```

And here what I have in my .bib file :

> @article{klaauw.96,
>    title={{Female labour supply and marital status decisions: A life-cycle model}},
>    author={{van der Klaauw}, Wilbert},
>    journal={Review of Economic Studies},
>    volume = {63},
>    number = {2},
>    pages = {199--235},
>    year={1996}
>   }
>   @article{klaauw.12,
>    title={{On the Use of Expectations Data in Estimating Structural Dynamic Choice Models}},
>    author={{van der Klaauw}, Wilbert},
>    journal={Journal of Labor Economics},
>    volume = {30},
>    number = {3},
>    pages = {521--554},
>    year={2012}
>   }
>   @article{stineb.96,
>    title={{An empirical investigation of teacher attrition}},
>    author={{Stinebrickner}, Todd},
>    journal={Economics of Education Review},
>    volume = {17},
>    number = {2},
>    pages = {127--136},
>    year={1996}
>   }
>   @article{stineb.12,
>    title={{An analysis of occupational change and departure from the labor force: Evidence of the reasons that teachers leave}},
>    author={{Stinebrickner}, Todd},
>    journal={Journal of Human Resources},
>    volume = {37},
>    number = {1},
>    pages = {192--216},
>    year={2012}
>   }

I get :

> (van der klaauw 1996, 2012)
>   (Stinebrickner 2012, 1996)

I don't understand why the outcome is not consistent. I think I should get :

> (van der klaauw 1996, 2012)
>   (Stinebrickner 1996, 2012)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are the titles of Stinebrickner's publications really "Title C" and "Title D"? If not, please provide the real titles.

Comment: Here, your document produces always the expected result...

Comment: I initially simplified the titles to have a MWE but I just noticed the code works well with those simplified titles. I edited the post and put the real titles and the problem shows up. Any insight ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are loading only the *cite*-style `authoryear-comp` with `citestyle=authoryear-comp`, *you do not load the bibliography style*. This you can see if you issue `\printbibliography`, it will have the format you get with `bibstyle=numeric`.

Because the bibliography style sets the `sorting` option, you are effectively using the sorting that `numeric` imposes and that is `sorting=nty` (name-title-year), but you expect `sorting=nyt`.

You have two options

1. Use `style=authoryear-comp` instead of `citestyle=authoryear-comp`, that way you also load theappropriate bibliography style
2. Specify `sorting=nyt` manually.